Azure 上の IIS に localhost でアクセスしようとすると not found になる
IIS 10.0 + ASP.NET + azureVM上でWebアプリケーションを動作させています。
azureVMのedgeブラウザを使用して自マシンにアクセスしたときの挙動でVMに振られたIPアドレスでのアクセスでは正常に動作可能なのですが、localhost および127.0.0.1を指定するとnot found 404となります。
・ping localhostは問題ないためルーティングテーブルは正常です。
・ウイルス対策ソフトは、ON/OFFで現象は変わりません。
・not found 404が表示されていることIPアドレス指定では動作することからIIS自体は稼働中です。
(127.0.0.1でIIS自体では表示できているためbindを加除しても現象は変わりません)
IISの設定内でリクエストアドレスによって動作が変わる設定箇所等ご存じありませんでしょうか。
apacheのVirtualHostタグのように
アクセスされるhostごとにサイトバインディングが変わってしまっているのだろうと想像しているのですが、いろいろ設定を見て回っても、どこかがわからず・・・

「localhost および127.0.0.1」はローカルループバックアドレスと言って、質問者さんがブラウザを動かしている PC 自身を指すということは理解してますか？

理解していますよ。

自己解決？しました。
サーバOSから自ホストに http://{この指定で動作が変わる}/context/****.aspx にアクセスするとしますと、
1. localhost or 127.0.0.1の場合
default web siteの基本設定に設定された %SYSTEM_ROOT%\wwwroot (デフォルト) に問答無用でアクセス（context/*****.aspx が存在しないためエラー）
2. azureVMに振られたIPアドレスを使用した場合
default web siteに追加した仮想ディレクトリにアクセスされているようです。
（context/*****.aspx が存在するため問題なし）

おそらく保証外の確認方法だと思いますが、
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config を確認すると、siteタグでくくられたXMLスキーマ上、以下の仕様と読み取れました。

127.0.0.1 or localhost の場合、どの仮想ディレクトリにアクセスさせる設定はない。
当然、VMにアサインされたIPアドレスの場合、どの仮想ディレクトリにアクセスさせる設定もない
bindアドレスの加除によって設定ファイルは変わっているが、127.0.0.1を追加しようが削除しようが現象は変わらない。
リクエストパスごとにどの仮想ディレクトリに委譲するかの設定は可能。

設定上、すべてのリクエストパスは、追加した仮想ディレクトリに処理を委譲するようになっている（そのためlocalhostアクセス以外の動作は問題なし）
よって127.0.0.1 or localhostでリクエストとした場合のみ、site基本設定の仮想ディレクトリに無条件で移譲されてしまっていると読み取りました。
default web siteの基本設定に追加した仮想ディレクトリのパスを指定することで、127.0.0.1/localhost/VMに割り振られたIPアドレスでも同じ結果となりました。
追加の仮想ディレクトリと基本設定のルート設定を思い通りに設定だけで操ることは難しそうです。

「http://{この指定で動作が変わる}/context/****.aspx」は IIS マネージャーで見てどこにあって、どういう設定になっているんですか？ 「仮想ディレクトリ」ではなくてアプリケーションではないのですか？

「思い通りに設定だけで操ることは難しそうです」とのことですが、その「思い」とは具体的にどういうことですか？  そもそも何がしたいのですか？

azureVM(Edge ⇔ IIS 10.0 ⇔ ASP.NET) と Windows 10 PC (Edge ⇔ IIS 10.0 ⇔ ASP.NET) とは同じということらしいですが、そうであれば、上の回答はいろいろ間違っているようです。そのあたりをクリアにしたいので、上の私のコメントに答えていただけませんか？

質問のコメント欄での私の質問、
「localhost および127.0.0.1」はローカルループバックアドレスと言って、質問者さんがブラウザを動かしている PC 自身を指すということは理解してますか？
に対する答えは、

理解していますよ。

とのことですが、であれば、「localhost および127.0.0.1」では接続できないことも理解できると思うのですが？
質問者さんの言う azureVM とは Microsoft が提供する IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service) で、物理的に離れた場所にある Microsoft のデータセンターのマシンにインターネットを介して接続して使っているのですよね？　
そして、質問の「IIS 10.0 + ASP.NET + azureVM上でWebアプリケーションを動作させています」というのは以下の構成なのですよね？
質問者の Windows PC のブラウザ ⇔ Internet ⇔ IaaS (IIS + ASP.NET)
理解が違っていたらその旨コメント欄に書いてください。
上の理解が合っていれば、ブラウザから「localhost および127.0.0.1」では IaaS の IIS に接続できません。グローバル IP でないと Internet を通りませんので。
質問者さんの azureVM が特別な仕組み（例えば「localhost および127.0.0.1」をグローバル IP に変換してくれるとか）を提供していれば分かりませんが、そんな仕組みはないですよね？

【追記】
誤解してました。
質問者の Windows PC のブラウザ ⇔ Internet ⇔ IaaS (IIS + ASP.NET)
という構成と思ってましたが、そうではなくて、以下のような構成なのですね？
azureVM (Edge ⇔ IIS ⇔ ASP.NET)
とすると azureVM には触ったこともない自分には分かりません。お役に立てずすみませんが他の方の回答をお待ちください。
なお、下のコメント情報「azureVMのedgeブラウザを使用してlocalhostを指定し自マシンにアクセスしたときの挙動」は質問欄を編集してそちらにも追記することをお勧めします。
以下、自分の Windows 10 の開発マシン内での話ですが・・・
azureVM (Edge ⇔ IIS ⇔ ASP.NET) の挙動が、もし、普通の Windows10 OS の開発マシンのローカル IIS 10.0 にデプロイした ASP.NET アプリと同じであれば、localhost または 127.0.0.1 でアクセスできるのはデフォルトでは Default Web Site 下に配置したリソースだけです。

ここに配置すれば、例えば上の MvcApp (ASP.NET MVC アプリ) には localhost または 127.0.0.1 でアクセスできます。開発マシンに振られたローカル IP アドレスでも同様です。

Default Web Site 下に存在しなければ HTTP 404 エラーになります。

質問者さんのケースではそういうこと（Default Web Site 下に存在しない）ではないですか？　「VMに振られたIPアドレスでのアクセスでは正常に動作可能」とのことですが、IIS でそういう設定もできますので。


興味を持っていただきありがとうございます。
わざわざlocalhost、127.0.0.1を指定してインターネットを介してアクセスしたいと受け取られるとは盲点でした。
azureVMのedgeブラウザを使用してlocalhostを指定し自マシンにアクセスしたときの挙動と書くべきでした。
apacheのVirtualHostタグのように
アクセスされるhostごとにサイトバインディングが
変わってしまっているのだろうと想像しているのですが、
いろいろ設定見て回っても、どこかがわからず・・・

上のコメントに対するレスを上の回答欄に追記しました

開発マシンでもazureVMでも動作は変わらないと思います（IIS10のため）
おっしゃる通り127.0.0.1リクエストの時、defaukt web siteの基本設定に指定された仮想ディレクトリにアクセスしているようです。
ただしIPアドレス指定の場合は、追加した仮想ディレクトリに正常にアクセスされているようです。
bindはbindであり、～IPアドレスがリクエストされたら、どの仮想ディレクトリを返すという設定ではないため無関係だと思います。

上のコメントの「追加した仮想ディレクトリ」というのは IIS マネージャーで見てどこにあって、どういう設定になっているんですか？ 「仮想ディレクトリ」ではなくてアプリケーションではないのですか？
